# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line

Tags: calculus

- $y=x^2$, $y=4$; about $y=4$.

*My solution is*: $\pi \int _{0}^{4}(4-x^2)^2dx$. Can you check my answer?

Comment: I think it should be from $-2$ to $2$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo why?

Comment: make the drawing${}$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I made the drawing. Since rotating about $y=4$, it should be from $0$ to $4$, shouldn't it? Can you explain clearly?

Comment: @Kahler I added an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the solid is rotated about a horizontal line, we note that to find the volume we can sum up a bunch of circles all passing through an axis parallel to the x-axis. The radius of any one of these arbitrary circles is $r=(4-x^2),$ where x is the x-coordinate of all the points on that circle. Now, the intersection points of the two curves are (-2, 4) and (2, 4). This means that the limits of integration are -2 and 2, as commented; the integral is $\pi\int_{-2}^2r\ dx=\pi\int_{-2}^2(4-x^2)^2\ dx,$ as the comment suggests.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: I have a questios that if the solid was rotated about vertical line in the question then we would take from $0$ to $4$, right?

Comment: yes, that would be the case, but the integrand would change

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion in the comments by Jorge is correct. It should be:

$$A = \pi\int_{-2}^{2}(4-x^2)^2dx$$

You're adding up all of the discs with the radii starting at $y=4$ and going down to $y=x^2$. All of the discs are aligned vertically, so you integrate over the bounds of $x$, which go from $-2$ to $2$.

In approximate discrete terms, "Take the disc at $x=-2$ plus the disc at $x=-1.9$ plus the disc at $x=-1.8$ ... plus the disc at $x=+1.9$ plus the disc at $x=+2$."

It appears that you were integrating over the bounds of $y$, which isn't what's needed here.

Comment: Thanks for answer.